# Delete a PFObject if I already have the object ID

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm working on deleting a PFObject in Parse.com.  However, I already have the object ID.

Is there a way to delete the entire entry based on the Object ID without doing a PFQuery for the object ID first?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `objectWithoutDataWithClassName:objectId:` to create an empty object representing your object on the server with that id. Then you can delete and save that object.

Comment: what would the total code be?  I just tried objectWithoutDataWithClassName:ObjectID:dependantGoalID.deleteInBackground()

Comment: I can write it in obj-c, I don't really do swift at the moment (so not 100% on the class method call syntax), it's just a class method call with 2 params so if you know that syntax it should be simple

Comment: got it, answering it below.  Thank you for the hep Wain.  You led me in the right direction.

Comment: Your code shows creating a normal object and settings the id, which is different (and shouldn't actually work)

Answer (score 0):

```
    let thisGoal = PFObject(className: "ParseClassName")
    thisGoal.objectId = savedObjectIdValue
    thisGoal.deleteInBackground()
```